# passing a struct to a function and loop through it

Tags: c, struct

Trying to pass a struct to a function and browse through it. Is this the correct way to pass a struct to a function? The for loop in the function view() doesn't seem to work. Any help with that too would be appreciated.

My structs:

```
typedef struct {
    char name[20];
    employee *list_employees;
    int empl_count;
} agency;
typedef struct {
    char name[30];
    int age;

} employee;
```

Important pars of the code:

```
int main()
{
//...
int nmbr_agencies;
agency *list_agencies = malloc(sizeof(agency) * nmbr_agencies);
view(&list_agencies, &nmbr_agencies);
}
void view(agence *ListA[], int *nmbr)
{
    int i=0;
    for (i = 0; i < *nmbr; i++){
        printf("name of agency: %s\n", ListeA[i]->name);
        printf("number of employees\n, ListeA[i]->empl_count);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

No.

You should just pass a single array if that is what you have, not pretend (in the call) that you have an array of pointers which you don't have.

Make the function:

```
void view(const agency *list, size_t number);
```

and call it like so:

```
view(list_agencies, nmbr_agencies);
```

Then inside the function, do direct accesses:

```
printf("name of agency: %s\n", list[i].name);
```

since you *don't* have an array of pointers.

Comment: @tetma I see an issue with the ordering of your structures How can you have employee within struct agency ? It should throw an error